# How to display logged in users Active Directory full name using PHP?

Tags: php, active-directory

I am trying to display the full name of a user in Active Directory on an Intranet page.  I can display their user id with:

$eadUserName = $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'];
echo $eadUserName;

but need to figure out a way to display their full name instead.  I am new to PHP so any info would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP LDAP extension in combination with `getenv("username")` function.

The php.net manual has a list of all posible variations of the extension:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php